# how to make lists of lists into one consecutive list r

Tags: r, list

Here is my list of lists

```
$cor
 [1] 0.10194656 0.09795653 0.18832356 0.12265421 0.09669338 0.13781369 0.16763787 0.15137726 0.10203826 0.12649443 0.16451622 0.18429656 0.21234920
[14] 0.18254895 0.10761731 0.15354220 0.13458206

$cor
[1] 0.3332299 0.3909873 0.3631544

$cor
 [1] 0.11601617 0.10834637 0.10138418 0.13864724 0.17582967 0.15005935 0.05481153 0.15443826 0.08987235 0.19109966 0.13404778 0.15816381
```

I want all values to be in one list in the order they appear.

Comment: That is a list of numeric vectors, not a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  But base R has an `unlist` function which outputs what you may be looking for:

```
c1 <- 1:5
c2 <- 6:10
cor <- list(c1, c2)
cor
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
unlist(cor)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following example data:

```
lst <- list(cor = 1:3, cor = 4:6)

lst
$cor
[1] 1 2 3

$cor
[1] 4 5 6
```

You could use the following, which places all items in one vector, in their original order:

```
do.call(c, lst)

cor1 cor2 cor3 cor1 cor2 cor3 
   1    2    3    4    5    6
```

`Reduce()` also works similarly:

```
Reduce(c, lst)

[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```